# Wordpress mobile drop down menu

Tags: javascript, css, wordpress

As I'm going travelling for 6 months, I have made a WordPress blog. It is hosted on [www.a88.dk](http://www.a88.dk)

So far the site works as I want it to more or less, except for one annoyance. The drop down menu called "Billeder" (pictures in Danish) is not working when I'm on the mobile site. Simply nothing happens when you click this menu point.

I have tried to google the issue and I found some similar issues. It seems that I have to add some javascript to detect clicking the button when in mobile mode. However, I'm uncertain of how to do this exactly. Any help is very much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can easily fix it with JavaScript, add this to your site:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('li.menu-item-has-children').click(function(){
    $(this).find('.sub-menu').toggle();
  })
});
```

For example: [Jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/x9ujpj1c/)

Comment: Works like a charm! Thanks a bunch :)

Answer (score 0):

If you have jquery enabled in your theme, you can add this to your child theme js file.

```
$('.menu-expand').on('click', function(){
    $(this).closest('li').find('.sub-menu').toggleClass('active');
});
```

This code add an event on the menu expand when it is clicked. The function search the sub-menu that is in the same li as the menu-expand, and it toggles the class `active` on it. To be able to show it with css.

So add this to your css

```
.sub-menu.active {
    // You could not use !important but you will have to set a stronger css selector than .sub-menu.active
    display: block !important;
}
```